# Reordering the subpanels of an ExtJS panel

Tags: extjs2

I have an ExtJS Panel which contains a label in the first row and second row. Later i have added 4 sub panels each contains a checkbox,  and 2 textfields( each sub panel in a row in the main panel). Then i have 2 Move up/Move down buttons which reorder these sub panels up/down by 1 row for each click of the up/down buttons. I am able to layout the main panel with all the subpanels but stuck at reordering the subpanels. How to handle this(reordering the subpanels) functionality in ExtJS?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to change panel elements dynamically is to call doLayout function after change.
Not prettiest but working example of your problem:

```
var Panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'first',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'text1',
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'text2',
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkbox'
    }]
})

var Panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'second',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'text1',
        xtype: 'textfield'},
    {
        fieldLabel: 'text2',
        xtype: 'textfield'}]
})

var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'main',
    items: [Panel1, Panel2]
})

new Ext.Window({
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [mainPanel],
    bbar: [{
        text: 'reorder',
        handler: function() {
            var swap = mainPanel.items.items[0];
            mainPanel.items.items[0] = mainPanel.items.items[1];
            mainPanel.items.items[1] = swap;
            mainPanel.doLayout();
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

This is for ExtJs 4.0.7, but trick works for earlier versions, just adjust panel creation syntax.